# What are the US sanctions on Iran's Supreme Leader?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, iran, sanctions

The Trump administration imposed sanctions on Iran's Supreme Leader Ali Khamenei today. It was also stated that sanctions will be imposed on Iran's Foreign Minister Javad Zarif in the upcoming week.

What exactly do these newly announced sanctions mean? Are they symbolic or should we expect economic consequences as well?

Comment: What I've always failed to understand is the US has **previously** announced 'we are applying maximum sanctions' (whether it is Iran or North Korea), and yet some time later new sanctions are announced. If we are already applying **maximum** sanctions how can those sanctions now be increased?

Comment: @BobE They mean the maximum they are willing to apply at the time.

Comment: Do you mean economic consequences for the leader or for whom?

Comment: For anybody. I would like to get an insight into the quantifiable consequences of these sanctions because the words I am reading on the news are too ambiguous to mean anything.

Answer (score 3):

They are supposed to restrict the actions of the two officials.  They should not have any effect on other Iranians not covered by them.  I don't know that I'd call them symbolic.  The idea is to pressure Khamenei and Zarif directly rather than apply sanctions that affect other Iranians to put pressure on them indirectly.

It's possible that they don't have sufficient international financial activity to be affected.  If so, perhaps they are symbolic.  I don't know enough of the finances of those two individuals to be able to say one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

The fresh sanctions are kind of 'isolated sanctions' in the sense that they don't affect Iranian assets in general. The new sanctions specifically target Iran’s supreme leader, Ali Khamenei, and other officials including eight Revolutionary Guard commanders.

It is alleged that the Islamic Revolutionary Guards Corps (IRGC) is involved in malicious activities in the region and are trying to destabilise the region. Also, Khamenei sits on billions of dollars worth business empire. So, the fresh sanctions, as the US puts it, are against the oppressive modus operandi of Iran's supreme leader.

[Here's an article by TheGuardian on this piece](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/jun/24/mike-pompeo-us-saudi-arabia-talks-iran-united-arab-emirates-tensions)

Comment: Please reference some of the claims you make. Please edit your answer to include some sources.

Comment: Added the source.

Comment: My problem is that phrases such as "billions of dollars", "empire of tyranny", and Supreme Leader's "assets" are very ambiguous, and I cannot find more information (or even one example) about the details of such assets in the reports. There seems to be no quantifiable example anywhere on the domain of these newly announced sanctions.